# Is there a library of default unit tests for .NET interface implementations?

Tags: .net, unit-testing

For example, I have a type which implements IDictionary, and I need test coverage to ensure that it does it properly. I just wondered if there is a repository of standard, reusable tests for this kind of thing anywhere; if there isn't, I might create one.

Comment: Not that I know of. If you do create one, please edit a link into this  question, or better yet ping me on Google+ and I'll contribute some tests. Probably nasty, fiddly ones :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. You have an implementation of IDictionary and wants to test that the implementation does what it suppose to do? If that is the case, I don't see any other way than writing a bunch of unit tests for that implementation. If you can find another test of IDictionary, which passes against your implementation, you could as well have used the standard implementation, rather than writing your own :)

Comment: If there isn't a suit already available, you could use Pex (http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/) to get you started.

Comment: Thomas: many types may implement IDictionary<TKey, TValue>; for example, ExpandoObject in the BCL does. Those implementations might all be different internally (e.g. ExpandoObject does not use hash codes) but their behaviour when being used through that interface should be consistent. That is the point of interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find anything which specifically met this need, so I made it. I've created a Github repo and added my IDictionary<TKey,TValue> test to it; hopefully people will fork and contribute more tests.

https://github.com/markrendle/InterfaceTests.Net

Answer (score 7):

I doubt there's a publicly available .net one, but the Mono project might be a good place to start?

Whether they're testing "the contract" of the interface, or the specific implementation, I'm not sure, but there's certainly tests for the Dictionary class:

https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/Test/System.Collections.Generic/DictionaryTest.cs

Comment: -1: if Mono _does_ have such tests, then this is an answer. If Mono _might_ have tests, then it is not.